# Javascript - How to filter object values with search input and get its key based on that?

Tags: javascript

```
const obj ={
  1: {name:"josh",age:2, symbol: "abc", id: 1},
  2: {name:"mike",age:4, symbol: "efg", id: 2}
}

const search = (input) => {
return Object.values(obj).filter(item => {
  return item.name.includes(input)
})
}

search("mi")
// returns: [ { name: 'mike', age: 4, symbol: 'efg', id: 2 } ]
```

1. How can I access the found objects id (id:1)
2. How can I get the found objects key (1: ...)

I am trying to find 1 and 2 of the object inside my array which matched my search input (see function)! In my filter I search for an object inside my array and see if one of those objects matches (or not) my search input. Then based on that I want to find the id of THAT object and its key
Thanks!

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) always returns an array, either empty or not. You can access items in this array by index. If you are totally sure there must be only one item in the resulting array, then probably access it by `search('mi')[0]`. The operation of accessing the first element is type-safe because Array#filter's signature guarantees that.

Comment: So it returns an array with an object so you reference the array and than the object? What is the issue you are having with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it right, except when you used Object.values you lost the object keys, check demo below

```js
const obj ={
  1: {name:"josh",age:2, symbol: "abc", id: 1},
  2: {name:"mike",age:4, symbol: "efg", id: 2}
}

const search = (input) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => {
    return obj[key].name.includes(input)
  })
  .map(foundKey => ({...obj[foundKey], key: foundKey }))
}


const result = search("mi")
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the search for this:

```
const search = input => Object.values(obj).findIndex(item => item.name.includes(input));
```

Your Search:

```
const index = search('mike');
```

Your ID:

```
const id = Object.keys(obj)[index];
```

Your Item:

```
const item = obj[id];
```